# Building a REST url query that supports a variety of operator arguments?

Tags: python, json, rest

I am looking for an easy way to build URLs to query data from a REST API that supports a variety of query parameters beyond just '=':

```
Users/?name=John&lastname=!Jones
```

This would return JSON data listing all users with the first name of John, that does not have the lastname of Jones.

Python's Requests library has the ability to specify parameters in a dictionary, like:

```
args= { "name" : "John", "lastname" : "Jones" }
```

This would let me use dictionaries to specify url parameters, But that would give me the url suffix:

```
Users/?name=John&lastname=Jones
```

It seems that Requests just inserts a '=' between the keys and values of the dict, and I need to be able to support many other operators.

One idea I do have is to write a class for building a url that I could use dot notation for each parameter:

```
buildquery('Users').equals( 'name', 'John').not('lastname','Jones')
```

Each dotfunction would append to the url string.

---

Is there a better way to build more complex url queries to a REST API in Python? Or should I roll my own class to handle it with methods to handle each type of operator?

**EDIT** Rereading the API docs, these modifiers would be prepended to the value. Updated examples to reflect this, but general idea remains the same: how to handle adding these modifiers in an intuitive way?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.  Parameters can only be specified as key-value pairs.  But you can just add your operators as part of the value.  For instance, just set lastname to "!Jones" so it passes `name=John&lastname=!Jones`, then parse the value to identify whatever operators you want.

Comment: Rereading the docs, you are right, those modifiers need to be added to the value. But the same idea still applies: what is the best way to handle inserting these sorts of arguments?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  If you have your args dict as, e.g., `args= { "name" : "John", "lastname" : "!Jones" }` it should work.  How you actually construct those arguments depends on where they're coming from (e.g., are users selecting names from a list or what).

Comment: I want to make a wrapper for this API to abstract away all the details about requesting and retrieving the data, and make requests in the most generic and intuitive way possible. Using dicts was just an example of one alternative I have seen to explicitly writing the url by hand.